# How to cast an enum ordinal as a String?

Tags: java, casting, enums, ordinal

I need to pass the ordinal value of an enum as a parameter to a `HashMap<String, String>`. In other words, I want to cast an ordinal as a String.

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
HashMap<String, String> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
myHashMap.put("foo", String.format("%s", MyEnum.BAR.ordinal()));
```

Is that the best way? The `.toString()` method isn't available here, and `(String)MyEnum.BAR.ordinal()` doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you using this construct? There are a number of cleaner ways organize the code, most notably with `Map<String, MyEnum>`.

Comment: @chrylis That would require major refactoring and affect many other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also could use

[String.valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29)

```
myHashMap.put("foo", String.valueOf(MyEnum.BAR.ordinal()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
myHashMap.put("foo", String.format("%d", Integer.toString(MyEnum.BAR.ordinal())));
```

or simply (credit @OldCurmudgeon)

```
myHashMap.put("foo", Integer.toString(MyEnum.BAR.ordinal()));
```

Disclaimer: Would have to agree with comments that using `Map<String, MyEnum>` is a better approach

Comment: Or even `myHashMap.put("foo", ""+ MyEnum.BAR.ordinal());`

Comment: Or even easier: `myHashMap.put("foo", Integer.toString(MyEnum.BAR.ordinal()));`. @OldCurmudgeon it is not a good practice convert something to `String` using `"" + ` concatenation, the fact that *works* doesn't mean is *good*.

Answer (score 1):

The `ordinal()` is an internal number which could change.  I suggest you just use

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("foo", MyEnum.BAR.toString());
```

or

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("foo", MyEnum.BAR);
```

or

```
Map<String, MyEnum> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("foo", MyEnum.BAR);
```

Comment: @chrylis You are right, but I thought that might be too much of a change. ;)

Comment: I honestly couldn't think of any situation where it makes sense that you'd want to store a `String` representation and store the ordinal simultaneously... something smells with the whole API, and this is the point where I put on my refactoring boots!

Answer (score 1):

The best way if you used `HashMap<String, Integer>` and did not convert ordinal to String

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is better to use enum name as key

```
MyEnum.BAR.name()
```

and conversion back

```
MyEnum.valueOf("BAR")
```